# import string by serial port and print on LCD display

Tags: microcontroller, pic

```
//================= konfigure LCD
// porta za podatoci e PORTB
sbit LCD_RS at RB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RB3_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB3_bit;
char name;
char txt[16];


void init(){
    PORTB = 0xFF;
    TRISB = 0x00;
    ANSEL = 0x00;
    ANSELH = 0x00;
    C1ON_bit = 0;
    C2ON_bit = 0;
    UART1_Init(9600);
    Delay_ms(100);
    Lcd_Init();
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
}
//=========================================================



void main()
{
    init();
    UART1_Write_Text("Start");
    UART1_Write(10);
    UART1_Write(13);
    do{
    }
    while(!UART1_Data_Ready());

    name = UART1_Read();
    if (name!='.')
    {
        strcpy(txt,"name");
        strcat(txt,name);
        Lcd_Out(1,1, txt);
        Delay_ms(1);
    }
    else
        Lcd_Out(2,1, "error");
}
```

I want to display `string="MYNAME"` on  LCD. I import the string on serial port, but it was not display on LCD. What is the error? Could someone help me? I use pic16f887 and pic simulator IDE. Is there some function or something else?

Comment: please help me, it is very important for me....

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the UART1_Data_Ready for each character, and put the receiving of characters into a loop which ends when you press the '.'.  Also, you need to  move the strcpy out of the loop  so you don't write over the output string on every character.

EDITED: replaced strcat, since it requires both variables to be strings.

I also added an echo to make sure the program is receiving the character correctly from the UART.

```
strcpy(txt,"name ");
while (1)
{
    while(!UART1_Data_Ready());

    name = UART1_Read();
    if (name!='.')
    {
        char i;

        UART1_Write(name);
        i = strlen(txt);
        txt[i] = name;      // add char to end of string
        txt[i+1] = '\0';    // add zero to terminate new string
        Lcd_Out(1,1, txt);
        Delay_ms(1);
    }
    else
    {
        UART1_Write(13);     // cr
        UART1_Write(10);     // lf
        break;
}
```

Comment: @user1011868, if you put a breakpoint on the line "if (name!='.')" (right after coming back from the read character), do you ever get there?  If so, what is the value of name?

Comment: I try with this code, but still does not work, display me on LCD only name , but not the value "kiki" which I sent by serial port...

Comment: just found another bug, you can't concatenate a char to a string.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: did you put in the breakpoint that I asked for earlier, so you can see the value of the 'name' variable after the call to UART1_Read?  Also, you could echo you character back -- I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I have another problem with task, I don't understand how to solve the first part. this is the link when the task is posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551622/explanation-of-router-checks-address. If you know please help me?